# How to show one Imageview on top of that another ImageVIew in IOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS please consider..Below is my screen what I designed

[image]

**AttendanceViewController**

```
class AttendanceViewController: UIViewController,UIApplicationDelegate,
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UINavigationControllerDelegate,
    CLLocationManagerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginstatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var displayloginimg: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        loginstatus.layer.zPosition = 1

    }

   // start give attendance
    @IBAction func giveLoginbtn(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

> Note: Camera Button is not showing when I load image in the
>   **displayloginimg: UIImageView!** I add this line `loginstatus.layer.zPosition = 1` so `Login Label` is showing,But Camera Button is not showing..

Comment: They both should be visible without this line:
`loginstatus.layer.zPosition = 1`.

Try to find what makes them disappear

Comment: @Tal Cohen No sir...initially   `login label` and `cameraButtons` both views are visible But when i   load image in the `displayloginimg: UIImageView!` then `label` and `cameraButtons` are not showing..

Comment: I don’t know what constraints you used, but maybe try to set height and width to the image so it won’t move when you change its image.

Comment: No sir...The problem is that my `cameraButton` and `loginlable` is hidding by `displayloginimg: UIImageView!` once I loaded image using url....

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense because you placed `displayloginimg` below them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bringSubviewtoFront` method move views that are in hierarchy to front means on top of another instead of `layer.zPosition`.

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: yourView)
```

Code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(loginstatus)

}

// start give attendance
@IBAction func giveLoginbtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let camButton = sender as! UIButton
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(camButton)
}
```

Comment: `@IBAction func giveLoginbtn(_ sender: Any) {

    }` for cameraButton how can I give..

Comment: Cast sender to UIButton like **let button = sender as! UIButton** and then to bring cameraButton to front **self.view.bringSubview(button)**

Comment: For reference, I've updated the code in answer. Have a look..!!

Comment: will check let u know

Comment: Thank for you help..when i click on hidden  button area then the camera Button is showing But I want to show camera button by default please help me how to acheive